# What part of Sanctuary City deportation is unconstitutional?

Tags: united-states, constitution, donald-trump, illegal-immigration

[The mayors of numerous](https://www.buzzfeed.com/salvadorhernandez/sanctuary-cities-are-promising-to-fight-trumps-immigration-o?utm_term=.uiAVKRk8O#.pyQJBvN67) **Sanctuary Cities** in the United States - those which shelter or allow undocumented immigrants - have promised to take the President to court. They have stated that his recent executive order asking them to deport local immigrants is **unconstitutional**. If enforced, the order would cut funding from any city that failed to abide by his directive.

While there are many social, political, and economical reasons to argue against the order, **what part of the Constitution are these sources referring to?**

**What specifically has been or can be argued, using the Constitution as a base, against this order?**

Comment: Welcome to the site, have you done any research on the Constitution in this regard?  Good question.  What the mayors are attempting in general is called "Nullification" by the way.  Just to get you started.

Comment: @KDog One site briefly mentioned the 10th Amendment but I want to see if that is credible or if there are additional violations being proposed.

Comment: See the two articles I reference below to Ben Cooper's answer.  They are a decent start to understand this.  I don't think the cities have much of a leg to stand on since Obama's stance in Arizona v US.  Arizona's case was much stronger than any on these mayors.  And they still lost.

Comment: @KDog but the Arizona case was fundamentally different from the present controversy.

Comment: @KDog But the Arizona case was trying to decide whether cities and municipalities _can_ enforce federal law, not whether they _can be compelled to do so_, right?

Comment: @reirab No.  The Arizona case was about Arizona enforcing a state law that was sympathetic to the federal one.  The Court, basing its decision upon the supremacy clause, didn't even look at the federal law in this instance, but at Obama's prosecutorial discretion in not enforcing it.  In this situation, you have muni's trying to actually nullify both federal law and prosecutorial discretion.

Comment: @KDog They did look at the federal law, and didn't care how discretion was actually used. What they cared about was that immigration is an area where the feds have occupied the field. It doesn't matter whether states are acting with or against any sort of federal policy, because there's no room for states to enforce any immigration policy of their own unless Congress expressly authorized it. But it's generally unconstitutional for the feds to force the states to help implement federal policy; just because states can't do X without permission, doesn't mean they can be forced to do X.

Comment: @cpast Paying states so they can nullify federal law is a perverse outcome.  And I disagree with you on some of the facts, especially your first sentence.  In any event the 10th amendment is a lousy argument because of Article 4, section 4, that does enumerate the power to the federal government.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This follows the principle of federalism which is rooted in the 10th amendment. To quote:

> The powers not delegated to the United States by the Constitution, nor prohibited by it to the States, are reserved to the States respectively, or to the people.

This has historically been interpreted by the courts to not allow the federal government to obligate local government to enforce federal laws and regulations. See [New York v. United States](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_v._United_States) (1992) as an example. The sanctuary cities are claiming that this permits them to not have to enforce federal immigration law.

It's worth noting that some Mayors, most notably Marty Walsh of Boston have committed to sheltering immigrants in public buildings. The legality of hiding immigrants from federal officials is much more questionable.

Comment: Reference to Arizona v United States is going to take precedence, it's much more recently decided on much more similar grounds.  And you have Obama to thank.  http://www.slate.com/articles/news_and_politics/jurisprudence/2012/06/the_supreme_court_s_arizona_immigration_ruling_and_the_imperial_presidency_.html

Comment: Also see the history of Nullification here.http://www.nysun.com/national/new-nullification-crisis-erupts-over-immigration/89881/

Comment: @KDog *Arizona* is much less on-point. The feds can stop the states from interfering in federal tasks. They cannot force the states to enforce federal policy. Blame the NRA for establishing that the feds can't make local sheriffs enforce federal gun laws. For the whole cutting funds thing, blame the Republican AGs who challenged Obama are for establishing that the feds can't coercively cut funding to get states to comply (small relevant cuts are fine, "no money unless you do X" is not).

Comment: I would also add that Article 4, section 4 of the Constitution so does enumerate the power to the Federal Government, so the 10th Amendment doesn't apply

Answer (score 2):

I agree with @Ben-Cooper that https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_York_v._United_States is a valid precedent (I'm not a lawyer), but that case explicitly permitted the federal government to use "monetary incentives" to compel states. So, Trump's plan to take money from cities that don't enforce the law is probably Constitutional.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/South_Dakota_v._Dole also confirmed the federal government can use "monetary incentives" to make states comply with federal wishes, even those that aren't actually laws.

The https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/National_Maximum_Speed_Law was never a federal law per se: it merely economically punished states that refused to pass a 55mph speed limit law.

Comment: > that case explicitly permitted the federal government to use "monetary incentives" to compel states. administrations of both parties have done that. the speed limits on highways for example are some of the better known ones. but hi, if someone wants to sue, they are entitled to their rights as well.

Comment: Monetary incentives are limited to non-coercive ones. See *NFIB v. Sibelius* -- even if the grants *are* somehow related to the behavior the feds want (which is true for highway funds and a drinking age law designed to reduce DUI, but not true for most federal funds and immigration policy), it's unconstitutional to threaten so much funding as to be coercive (the feds couldn't strip states that didn't expand Medicaid of all Medicaid funding).

Comment: @cpast My reading of https://www.law.cornell.edu/supremecourt/text/11-393 is that Congress also can't compel commerce: in other words, they can't force people in the States to buy anything (such as medical insurance). However, you are also correct: the Circuit court rejected the coercion argument, but the Supreme Court appears to have agreed with it.